# Why can't I push to an array in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I can't seem to push an object to array in state from an API. This is my code

```
      async _fetchData(number){
        try{
          await console.log('asd',number)
          let response = await fetch( 'https://www.beanlinked.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/'+this.state.News[number].featured_media)
          let responseJson = await response.json()
          await console.log("responseJson")
          let tempURL = responseJson.guid
          let url = tempURL.rendered

          for (var i = 0; i < this.state.News.length; i++) {
            const items = this.state.News;
            items[number].URLOnSever = url;

          }

          this.state.News.push({
            URLOnSever : url
          })
          console.log("imageurl",this.state.News.URLOnSever)

          return url
        }catch(e){
          console.log('problem'+e)
        }
      }
```

I just want to push the new URL to `this.state.News`.

Comment: It's not undefined... you're not logging the right thing. `this.state.News[this.state.News.length - 1].URLOnServer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mutate state, which you are doing with `Array#push` -- mutating an array inside state. Use [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) instead to create a *new array* with the old array plus added elements set into state instead of pushing to the old one:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  News: [
    ...prevState.News,
    { URLOnServer: url }
 ]
}));
```

This will set `News` to the previous state's `News` array contents (via [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_array_literals)) plus the new object. It's the same as your code, but without mutation of `state` directly. Learn more at [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

Comment: I don't quite understand. Your method seems like create an array containing two object: the previous state and { URLOnServer: url }.

Comment: this.setState(prevState => ({
                
                News: [
                  prevState.News,
                  { URLOnServer: url }
                ]
              }));

Comment: @YingyongZheng yes.. look at the link posted in Andrew's answer. or more specifically... [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: @YingyongZheng Sorry for not getting back, I didn't get your response in my inbox. You have to use spread syntax to spread to previous News's elements into the array, along with the new object. For example: `var foo = [1, 2, 3] var bar = [...foo]` - `bar` is now a new array with the same elements as `foo`: `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Hey, I try your code. I am sorry about I didn't describe my situation clearly.

Comment: The state news contains 10 objects. your code just assume it is a simple array. What should I with that ojects? Insert 10 url to each of them. tThanks

Comment: Thank you. I will try it again. Do I need to put something like this:

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < this.state.News.length; i++) 
        {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          News: [
            ...prevState.News[i],
            { URLOnServer : url }
          ]
        }));
      }

Comment: Could you please have look at my whole code. It pasted above

Comment: @YingyongZheng Andrew Li has given you the correct answer. You do not manual set state in `react`. You use the `setState` method of a react component. You do this exactly how he showed you, or without a function you can use an object representing the portion of state you wish to update. If you use a function it ensures `setState` requests are processed consecutively when dispatched in rapid succession. Without a function you will have a merged batch update to state when there are many `setState` requests in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to push something to an array stored in a state is just grab the state and store it in a variable. Push the item to that variable and set the state.

```
const temp = this.state.list;
temp.push(newItem);
this.setState({ list: temp });
```