# Other than shouldComponent update, why not mutate state in React?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a complex state object. And the portion of the object graph I want to update is deeply nested.

Is there any drawback to simply mutating the state object and then replacing the entire state, like this:

```
this.state.x.y.z = "new value"
this.setState(newState)
```

I can only think of two reasons you might *not* want to do this:

1. shouldComponentUpdate will not work correctly
2. you are a fan of functional programming

Other than that, I am about 99% convinced that this is a perfectly valid style of React programming.

I just wanted to verify this hypothesis. Perhaps someone knows something that I don't that invalidates my hypothesis.

PS: I am aware of the technique for using setState to update just one or two fields of your state object. I am also aware of the various functional programming techniques for updating deeply nested portions of an object tree with out mutating the original. So please don't side track on that topic.

Edit: There is a similar question here [ReactJS: Why shouldn't I mutate nested state?][1]. But my question is subtly different. The answer to *his* question is simply: because shouldComponentUpdate will not work correctly.

My question includes the caveat "besides shouldComponentUpdate and the benefits of functional programming".

Comment: IMO it's an unnecessary extra point of failure. What if you accidentally mutate and forget to set state? Mutation is a huge problem when it comes to predictability sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS: Why shouldn't I mutate nested state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125063/reactjs-what-so-bad-about-mutating-nested-state)

Comment: @AndrewLi What if you accidentally forget to call setState? I'm not sure this is a valid answer. You could forget anything.

Comment: how about when multiple set states are called? how do you prevent your mutated state from being overwritten from another state transition? The only way to garentee that your state will reflect exactly what you want it to is by putting it in a queue like they recommend. seems like a fairly simple concept. Don't mutate state. The docs explicitly say you shouldn't... [just follow the recommended way to update state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260815/2733506)

Answer (score -1):

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) say ...

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

When you use

```
this.state.x.y.z = "new value" // line 1
this.setState(newState)
```

you are relying on the assumption that setState will be executed immediately after line 1. This is not guaranteed.

Comment: I believe the async concern is more referring to the case where you 1) call setState and 2) then try and use that state. That is not applicable here.